# Handle dynamic request body - java rest api

Tags: java, json, api, rest, request

I have a dynamic request body as below.
It can be either

```
{
   "emp_id" : "1234",
   "ids" : ["555", "666"]
}
```

or

```
{
   "name" : "john",
   "ids" : ["333", "444"]
```

How can I handle this in request pojo class?
Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```java
class Foo {
    @SerializedName("emp_id")
    private String empId;
    @SerializedName("ids")
    private List<String> ids;
    // getter setter    
}
```

- Have you ever try any the Json processing library before? (Jackson, gson,...)